# Submenú no se muestra

Tags: html, css, nav, li

¡Hola! Estoy intentando recrear una página web, y a la hora de crear un submenú, el submenú no se muestra.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<nav class="navegacion">
        <ul class="menu">
         <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Music</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Connect</a>
             <ul  class="submenu">
                <li><a href="">Amazon</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Apple Music</a></li>             
             </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
        </nav>




.menu > li{
position:relative;
display: inline-block;    
}

.menu >li >a{
display:block;  
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover{
color:grey;   
}

.submenu{
position:absolute;   
width: 100%;
display:none;


}

.submenu li a{
display:block;

text-decoration: none;   
font-size: 13px;


}

.submenu li:hover .submenu{
display:block;


}
```

Me he asegurado de cerrar bien las etiquetas, y de escribir display:block; en el hover, pero soy algo novato aún en este tema y no sé realmente donde he podido equivocarme.¿Qué es lo que me falla?

Answer (score 0):

Este es un submenu que puede implementar y que puedes ver en W3Schools, es un sitio que tiene muy buenos recursos y tutoriales. Espero te sirva, puedes consultar varios de estos [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Suerte

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Considera checar [answer], una edición explicando tu aporte no caería mal

Comment: Hola, ya se mejoró la respuesta, gracias

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, a ver si consigo ver el fallo con algunos ejemplos.¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar algo así:

```
<style>
.menu>li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.submenu li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#sub:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}
```

```
<nav class="navegacion">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Music</a></li>
    <li id="sub"><a href="">Connect</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Amazon</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Apple Music</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Lo he probado y sigue sin funcionar...de todos modos, ¡muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: mmm que raro, puedes anexar como lo probaste?